# At 80°C a solution having pH = 7 is?

Tags: acid-base, ph

When I came across this question I couldn't understand whether, they are asking the nature of solution at 25°C which has pH = 7 at 80°C  or nature of solution at 80°C which has pH = 7 at 25°C ?
Because in the first case answer would be acidic and in second case answer would be basic

Comment: for sure it refers to some exercise about Nerst Equation and dependence of pH on temperature but please give more context and try to reformulate the question. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neutral $\pu{pH}$ is half the $\pu{pK}$ value for water dissociation, and of course the latter is almost exactly $14$ at $25°$C and one bar. That's where we get $\pu{pH}=7$ for a neutral solution — under ambient conditions.

The open source reference [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1928231) gives an expression for $\pu{pK_w}$ as a functoon of temperature and pressure. **Because water autoionization is endothermic, $\pu{pK_w}$ will go down on heating and the neutral $\pu{pH}$ will follow suit.** For instance, at low pressure and $75°$C $\pu{pK_w}=12.70$, so the corresponding neutral $\pu{pH}$ would be $6.35$. A solution with $\pu{pH}=7$ at this temperature would be basic; if cooled to ambient temperature the solution would autoionize less and we'd see the $\pu{pH}$ rise above $7$.

**Reference**

1. Andrei V. Bandura; Serguei N. Lvov (2006). "The Ionization Constant of Water over Wide Ranges of Temperature and Density" . *J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data* **35**, 15–30.
   https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1928231